# excel/google sheet: if current month then do a formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have current day in G7 as =TODAY()
Then I need to check if G7 month is the same as in cells E16 (February), G16 (march), I16 (April),... and so until December.
I don't need the year

If G7 is the same month written on E16 then I need to perform a calculation into cell E18, G18, I18,... and so:
=If(I18>0;(SUM($D$10+I18)-(Sum(K$21:K)));"0")

Otherwise those cells should display a zero 0.

[image: Image of my spreadsheet]

Thank you
H

Comment: Share google-sheet link so that we can edit.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((I18>0)*(MONTH(G$7)=MONTH(E16)); SUM(D$10+I18)-SUM(K$21:K); 0)
```

Comment: Dear player0 thank you for your reply. The formula didn't work. The result is always zero. I might be doing something wrong.
I need to insert the formula in K$18, there I need to check if K$16 is the current month according to %G%7. If it is, then it should execute this: If(I18>0;(SUM($D$10+I18)-(Sum(K$21:K)));"0") otherwise show a zero.

Comment: @Horacsio can you share a copy of your sheet?